# Kafka's Replicas handling mechanism?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have two questions.

1. I wonder how to sychronized leader partion and follower partions.
   If leader partition receive a message, then the leader broadcasting to follower partition on background communication? but It seemed kafka config file does not include these features(synchronization port info etc.)
2. If assume the following architecture.

   - Two brokers - Two partition - Two replicas
   - Broker#1 - leader partition#1, follower partition#2
   - Broker#2 - leader partition#2, follower partition#1

Sending messages will be round-robin to these two brokers...

If message#1 go to Broker#1(partition#1) and Broker#1 was shut down,

then broker#2 open the follower partition#1 and broker#2 has active two leader partition (for delivering the message#1)?

Answer (score 0):

1. This is already handled by Kafka. You only need to define the replication factor for a topic. According to [Kafka docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#intro_distribution),

> The partitions of the log are distributed over the servers in the
>   Kafka cluster with each server handling data and requests for a share
>   of the partitions. Each partition is replicated across a configurable
>   number of servers for fault tolerance.
>
> Each partition has one server which acts as the "leader" and zero or
>   more servers which act as "followers". The leader handles all read and
>   write requests for the partition while the followers passively
>   replicate the leader. If the leader fails, one of the followers will
>   automatically become the new leader. Each server acts as a leader for
>   some of its partitions and a follower for others so load is well
>   balanced within the cluster.

2. Your question is not clear. I believe my [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48419410/is-kafka-reliable-when-used-as-a-message-bus-in-micro-services/48423522#48423522) should shed some light with regards to kafka partitions, distribution of messages and fault tolerance.